# &nbsp when switch encoding type turn into weird character

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I use `&nbsp` in my web page, and when switch between different encoding, it becomes weird character, as you can see from below screen shot, it turn into chinese character, with other encoding, it become `accented A` character. For spacing, I will not use &nbsp anymore, but my JSF page, I need an empty label so I use

```
h:outputLabel value="&nbsp"
```

Now I am not sure what can I replace this above code with, to avoid these weird character to come up on my page. Please help

[image]

Comment: I presume you can't just use a space?

Comment: What do you mean "switch between different encoding"? What VDL (JSP or Facelets) are you using?

Comment: @McDowell: what I mean is between UTF, Korean KSC5601, Japanese EUC ... kjetilh: give the space does not seems to work for me.

Comment: Please copypaste the character in text. I'm curious to its UTF-8 byte sequence. As to switching between encoding, how and why exactly are you doing that?

Comment: @BalusC: Â -> this is encoding `ISO-8859-1`, 혻혻혻혻 -> this is encoding `KSC5601`. How: I create a PhaseListener, in `afterPhase`, I did `((HttpServletResponse) o).setCharacterEncoding(getCharacterEncoding());`. Why: the requirement is that the web application allow the customer to switch between different encoding type

Comment: I posted an answer. But this is a really strange requirement. UTF-8 (as JSF by default uses) covers every single character which mankind is aware of, including the ones definied in e.g. ISO-8859-X and KSC5601. You're basically allowing the enduser to change it to a more inferior encoding which doesn't support any character like Unicode/UTF-8. For what reason?

Answer (score 2):

You need to control the JSF view encoding via `<f:view encoding>`, not by manually setting `HttpServletResponse#setCharacterEncoding()` outside JSF's control. Otherwise JSF is still writing the response using the default UTF-8 encoding and you're basically only telling the browser afterwards that it's in a different encoding and hence the browser interprets it wrongly.

```
<f:view encoding="#{bean.encoding}">
```

As to the weird characters which you're seeing, [the `&nbsp;` exist in UTF-8 of bytes `0xC2` and `0xA0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). When those bytes are by the receiver (read: the webbrowser) incorrectly been interpreted using ISO-8859-1, then you get according [its codepage layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Codepage_layout) indeed respectively the characters `Â` and another non-breaking space. When those bytes are incorrectly been interpreted using KSC5601, then you get according [EUC-KR codepage layout](http://www.moransoft.com/euckr.html) indeed the character `혻`.

Answer (score 1):

For `&nbsp` use the value `&#160;`

Please refer [HTML ISO-8859-1 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Comment: it looks both &#160; and &#xa0 do not work. it still got map to weird character.

Comment: Instead of `h:outputLabel` can you give a try for `h:outputText` ?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `&nbsp` should have a semicolon at the end:

```
&nbsp;
```

I don't think that would be causing this problem, however.

Is there a reason you can't simply use " " or leave it blank altogether?

```
h:outputLabel value=" "
h:outputLabel value=""
```

You shouldn't be using it for styling though. Instead, you can simply:

```
button.myCancelButton { margin-left:40px; }
radio.myColumnsRadio { margin-left:40px; }
```

Also if you're wanting your radio buttons to have equal spacing between them, you'd either wrap them in a container with a fixed width or put them in a table:

```
span.myRadioContainer { width:100px; display:inline-block; }
```

Or (HTML solution, not sure how JSF works):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio"/></td>
            <td><input type="radio"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio"/></td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cdyQN/).